# How to bypass 255 character limit of VBA mass replace function?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub MultiFindNReplace()
    'Update 20140722
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"

    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set ReplaceRng = Application.InputBox("Replace Range :", xTitleId, Type:=8)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
        InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Source:
[Extend Office - How To Find And Replace Multiple Values At Once In Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1873-excel-find-and-replace-multiple-values-at-once.html)

Data type: 
[Using the Excel Application.InputBox method](http://codevba.com/excel/application_inputbox.htm#.W3-RTehKiF5)

I tried to replace `Type:=8` with `Type:=2` for text instead of range, but it didn't work. Please help me by pass the 255 character limit.

Example Data:
[Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1coaiPGE_ne5XcX0X8HaRT3olUZGkFQs0fKokMBwKh6Q/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you explain more about what you're trying to do, and how this limit is a problem?  It may be helpful to see a sample of the data you're starting with, and what you need to end up with.

Comment: You're welcome (and Welcome to [so]!) ...I think I know a solution but need to know a bit more, about what you're trying to do

Comment: if you run the code in the vba, it will ask for the original values that needed to be change, then it will as for the replace range(which is at least 2 horizontal cells. which the first one is the finding value, and the second one is the replacement value).

Comment: You could split the target into 2, 3 or more pieces, work on each separately then recombine them.

Comment: If the replacement value is longer than 255 character it will say run time error or some thing similar.

Comment: in my case, the original value is 20x100 or more cells stack near the others so i can't do it by hand by separating them then recombine them. But that is a good idea.

Comment: I think its a bit limitation of the "range" type. For it being only 8bit. 0-255 character max. I hope that explain my problem

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with proper example data so everyone here can reproduce and test it?

Comment: yes, i did, please look for the example worksheet, you can copy it to excel.

Comment: is the example okay?

Comment: So do always need to replace the whole cell content or also just a part of the cell content?

Comment: sometimes its the whole cell content, some times its part of the cell. If its easier for you to do either one or both, i will take it. thanks you so much.

Comment: I will take anything. I assume it would be easier for you if its whole cell content,  if it is, then please do so if its simpler for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Replace Whole Cell Content

So my idea to replace whole cell contents is:

1. Read replacements into a dictionary
2. Read data into an array
3. Replace in array
4. Write array back to cells

I choose the array because using arrays is much faster than working with cells. So we have only one slow cell reading and one slow cell writing and working with the array is fast.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MultiReplaceWholeCells()
    Const xTitleId As String = "KutoolsforExcel"

    Dim InputRange As Range
    Set InputRange = Range("A2:F10") 'Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)

    Dim ReplaceRange As Range
    Set ReplaceRange = Range("A12:B14") 'Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)

    Dim Replacements As Object
    Set Replacements = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'read replacements into an array
    Dim ReplaceValues As Variant
    ReplaceValues = ReplaceRange.Value

    'read replacements into a dictionary
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To ReplaceRange.Rows.Count
        Replacements.Add ReplaceValues(iRow, 1), ReplaceValues(iRow, 2)
    Next iRow

    'read values into an array
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = InputRange.Value

    'loop through array data and replace whole data
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = 1 To InputRange.Rows.Count
        For c = 1 To InputRange.Columns.Count
            If Replacements.Exists(Data(r, c)) Then
                Data(r, c) = Replacements(Data(r, c))
            End If
        Next c
    Next r

    'write data from array back to range
    InputRange.Value = Data
End Sub
```

---

#### Replace Part Of Cell Content

For replacing a part of a cell this would be slower:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MultiReplaceWholeCells()
    Const xTitleId As String = "KutoolsforExcel"

    Dim InputRange As Range
    Set InputRange = Range("A2:F10") 'Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)

    Dim ReplaceRange As Range
    Set ReplaceRange = Range("A12:B14") 'Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)

    'read replacements into an array
    Dim ReplaceValues As Variant
    ReplaceValues = ReplaceRange.Value

    'read values into an array
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = InputRange.Value

    'loop through array data and replace PARTS of data
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = 1 To InputRange.Rows.Count
        For c = 1 To InputRange.Columns.Count
            Dim iRow As Long
            For iRow = 1 To ReplaceRange.Rows.Count
                Data(r, c) = Replace(Data(r, c), ReplaceValues(iRow, 1), ReplaceValues(iRow, 2))
            Next iRow
        Next c
    Next r

    'write data from array back to range
    InputRange.Value = Data
End Sub
```

If you only need to replace whole cell contents use the first one which should be faster.

---

#### Procedure to Do Both Replacement Types

Or if you need both write a procedure so you can chose if you need to replace `xlWhole` or `xlPart`. Even a different output range would be possible.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestReplace()
    Const xTitleId As String = "KutoolsforExcel"

    Dim InputRange As Range
    Set InputRange = Range("A2:F10") 'Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)

    Dim ReplaceRange As Range
    Set ReplaceRange = Range("A12:B14") 'Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)


    MultiReplaceInCells InputRange, ReplaceRange, xlWhole, Range("A20") 'replace whole to output range
    MultiReplaceInCells InputRange, ReplaceRange, xlPart, Range("A30") 'replace parts to output range

    MultiReplaceInCells InputRange, ReplaceRange, xlWhole 'replace whole in place
End Sub

Public Sub MultiReplaceInCells(InputRange As Range, ReplaceRange As Range, Optional LookAt As XlLookAt = xlWhole, Optional OutputRange As Range)
    'read replacements into an array
    Dim ReplaceValues As Variant
    ReplaceValues = ReplaceRange.Value

    'read values into an array
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = InputRange.Value

    Dim r As Long, c As Long, iRow As Long

    If LookAt = xlPart Then
        'loop through array data and replace PARTS of data
        For r = 1 To InputRange.Rows.Count
            For c = 1 To InputRange.Columns.Count
                For iRow = 1 To ReplaceRange.Rows.Count
                    Data(r, c) = Replace(Data(r, c), ReplaceValues(iRow, 1), ReplaceValues(iRow, 2))
                Next iRow
            Next c
        Next r
    Else
        'read replacements into a dictionary
        Dim Replacements As Object
        Set Replacements = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        For iRow = 1 To ReplaceRange.Rows.Count
            Replacements.Add ReplaceValues(iRow, 1), ReplaceValues(iRow, 2)
        Next iRow

        'loop through array data and replace WHOLE data
        For r = 1 To InputRange.Rows.Count
            For c = 1 To InputRange.Columns.Count
                If Replacements.Exists(Data(r, c)) Then
                    Data(r, c) = Replacements(Data(r, c))
                End If
            Next c
        Next r
    End If

    'write data from array back to range
    If OutputRange Is Nothing Then
        InputRange.Value = Data
    Else
        OutputRange.Resize(InputRange.Rows.Count, InputRange.Columns.Count).Value = Data
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: how to use it? I can see the inputrange, and replacementrange, but no output cell.

Comment: The last line `InputRange.Value = Data` writes the data back in place where the input data was before. I ran this code on your example, so at least there it should work out of the box.

Comment: i see i see, you replace the original value with the new values. so there is no need for choosing a new output cell. thanks you.

Comment: @SimonLe If you need to do both replace types (whole and part) then you could even put this in an extra procedure for both types. See my 3rd edit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on what data you have and what you're trying to do, but I think you will have more success if you use the:

- MSDN : [**`Replace` Function** (VBA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/replace-function)

...instead of:

- Office Support: [**`Range.Replace` Method** (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Replace)

The second one is basically a worksheet function, therefore subject to various limits that the first one doesn't have.

Your code should require only minor changes to adapt to the `Replace` function.

Comment: it's mostly text.

Comment: the second one can replace a huge 100,000 value at a time, which i cant do it by hand with the first one i believe.

Comment: lets  me check out the first one real quick, thanks you.

Comment: no, I cant do it, the main point of the mass replace vba code is to replace many cells at one, the first one only replace 1 value at the time. Or may be i dont know how to use it? what do you think?

Comment: The first function should be implemented in a loop indeed.

Comment: This is the right anwser from what the title sugests. It worked for me, thx