# Type Mismatch in Replace function

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch, find-replace

I have thousands of rows where column H has cells with multiple pipe-delimited values that I am trying to use VBA Find/Replace on. If there weren't multiple pipe-delimited values in each cell I could just VLOOKUP (something more in my wheelhouse) to get what I am after. The beginning of the script simply copies column H into a new column I so I can retain the original column H and then begins find/replacing information from column B (i,2) of a secondary Worksheet titled Text.

I know the script works because I already use it in another workbook to do essentially the same thing. It even works in this workbook if I switch the data in column B of the Text worksheet with data from column C...no mismatch error. So what is the difference between the data? This is where I'm even further out of my comfort zone...it looks like the data I can successfully return without issue is all text strings, whereas the data I actually want to return (move from the Text worksheet to the Data worksheet) is mixed, some of it is pure numbers and some is mixed numbers/text. As it is looping, it successfully replaces some values before erroring, and those that were successfully replaced are of the mixed variety, so I suspect my Type Mismatch is due to some of the data I am trying to pull in being pure numbers, but I can't really tell.

*Note that when I paste the code here I can't figure out how to get the de-bug yellow highlighted section to show for you - but it starts at "datasheet.Columns"...and is those last 3 lines before "Next i". I attached a screenshot. [WhatIseeScreenie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQbxU.png)*

```
Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

        Dim abvtab() As Variant
        Dim ltsheet As Worksheet
        Dim datasheet As Worksheet
        Dim lt As Range

        'Change Lookup to the sheet name with lookup table.
        Set ltsheet = Sheets("Text")

        'Change Data to the sheet name with data.
        Set datasheet = Sheets("Data")

        'Change first Range to the top left cell in lookup table.
        'Change second Range to top right cell.
        Set lt = ltsheet.Range("A1", ltsheet.Range("B1").End(xlDown))

        abvtab = lt

        For i = 1 To UBound(abvtab)
            datasheet.Columns("I").Replace What:=abvtab(i, 1), Replacement:=abvtab(i, 2), LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked what's it the cell when it errors? Do you have any error values?

Comment: My only error is the generic Run Time Error '13': Type Mismatch. I can't tell which cell or value is causing the error. I tried looking up some tutorials on how to do this with error handling and msgbox to identify the cell that caused the error, but I couldn't figure it out because every example I found had a type mismatch for such a different use case that their error handling code just didn't work in my code.

Comment: When it errors, debug, go into the VBE and hover over `abvtab(i, 1)` and you should see the value.

Comment: isn't abvtab a Range rather than an Array?

Comment: @SJR - OMGoodness! The more you know, right? Hovering both abvtabs gives me the data, and hovering the "i" tells me the row in the Text worksheet that has the data that is causing the problem. The data is a long string of text...is there a limit on string length?

Comment: The failing replace value is 454 characters including spaces. Shortening it dramatically seems to have allowed a different (also long) text statement to be the problem. So unless I deleted some problematic hidden character, this seems to confirm there is a character limit on the Replace function. Any way around this (I can't actually change the data outside this process de-bugging).

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997789/how-to-bypass-255-character-limit-of-vba-mass-replace-function

Comment: SJR - I saw that too, but couldn't really understand how to use the one they are suggesting - not sure what changes to make: "you will have more success if you use the:

MSDN : Replace Function (VBA)
...instead of:

Office Support: Range.Replace Method (Excel)"